# Replace UniCode with space in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace unicode characters with space. For example, I have this string

> This was a very successful meeting.\u000b\u000bWe agreed on several topics:\u000b New strategy\u000b Development ressources\u000b Project optimization

and I want to replace `\u000b` with <kbd>space</kbd>.
Currently, I am doing it this way i.e.

```
var str = "This was a very successful meeting.\u000b\u000bWe agreed on several topics:\u000b";
var replaceStr = str.replace(/[\u000b\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000-\u2009\u200a​\u200b​\u202f\u205f​\u3000\u000b-]/g, ' ');
```

but it's not replacing these unicode characters with space.

Thank you

Comment: If I try it out in Browser-Console it works. Are you sure you continue working with `replaceStr` instead of `str`?

Comment: yes. I  am doing console 'replaceStr'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing unescaped Unicode code point that probably means that backslash character is escaped in the source. In this case, you can replace the code point with a character it represents:

```js
function unescapeUnicode(raw) {
  return raw.replace(
    /\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/gi,
    (_, c) => String.fromCharCode(Number.parseInt(c, 16))
  )
}

const input = 'This was a very successful meeting.\\u000b\\u000bWe agreed on several topics:\\u000b New strategy\\u000b Development ressources\\u000b Project optimization'

document.body.textContent = unescapeUnicode(input)
```